# Can't mount file on windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, windows-container

When i try to mount the config file on docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
    myService:
    ...
    volumes:
        - c:\DOCKER_DATA\myService.config:c:\MyService.exe.config
```

i get:

> > Cannot create container for service myService: invalid volume specification: 'c:\DOCKER_DATA\myService.config:c:\myService.exe.config:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this functionality is not supported on windows containers as posted [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30555).